# Overwrite basic functionality of Action Mapping and Parameters in a .net Web API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I would like to encode the URL (excluding the origin) of all the requests to Base64. Whenever a request is made it should decode the URL, find the respective Controller and Action and call it with the respective parameters.

Is there a function that I can overwrite (perhaps in `global.asax` or `webapiconfig.cs`) that will get called whenever a request is being made?

Comment: This can help you get a good understanding on global.asax [http://aspalliance.com/1114_Understanding_the_Globalasax_file.3](http://aspalliance.com/1114_Understanding_the_Globalasax_file.3)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you work with asp.net mvc and all fancy .net core middleware are not a thing yet, you could look into custom [`handler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/httpclient-message-handlers).
You theoretically could write the bootstrap code directly in `global.asax`, but as it by default calls through to WebApiConfig.Register():

```
 GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

it's probably a better place for things to do with WebAPI.

#### App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs

```cs
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            // Web API routes
            config.MessageHandlers.Add(new TestHandler()); // if you define a handler here it will kick in for ALL requests coming into your WebAPI (this does not affect MVC pages though)
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), new MyControllerSelector(config)); // you likely will want to override some more services to ensure your logic is supported, this is one example

            // your default routes
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "DefaultApi", routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional});

            //a non-overlapping endpoint to distinguish between requests. you can limit your handler to only kick in to this pipeline
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "Base64Api", routeTemplate: "apibase64/{query}", defaults: null, constraints: null
                //, handler: new TestHandler() { InnerHandler = new HttpControllerDispatcher(config) } // here's another option to define a handler
            );
        }
    }
```

and then define your handler:

TestHandler.cs

```cs
    public class TestHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            //suppose we've got a URL like so: http://localhost:60290/api/VmFsdWVzCg==
            var b64Encoded = request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.Remove(0, "/apibase64/".Length);
            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(b64Encoded);
            string decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data); // this will decode to values
            request.Headers.Add("controllerToCall", decodedString); // let us say this is the controller we want to invoke
            HttpResponseMessage resp = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            return resp;
        }
    }
```

Depending on what exactly you want your Handler to do, you might find that you will also have to supply your custom `ControllerSelector` implementation:

#### WebApiConfig.cs

```
// add this line in your Register method
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), new MyControllerSelector(config));
```

#### MyControllerSelector.cs

```cs
    public class MyControllerSelector : DefaultHttpControllerSelector
    {
        public MyControllerSelector(HttpConfiguration configuration) : base(configuration)
        {
        }

        public override string GetControllerName(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            //this is pretty minimal implementation that examines a header set from TestHandler and returns correct value
            if (request.Headers.TryGetValues("controllerToCall", out var candidates))
                return candidates.First();
            else
            {
                return base.GetControllerName(request);
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't know enough about your specific environment so this is far from being complete solution, but hopefully it outlines one avenue for you to explore

Comment: Complete answer .. Just copy paste and go for it